# Argox OS-2130D PPLA Ubuntu stickers print

Tags: ubuntu, printing, serial-port, label, drivers

I need to print stickers in Ubuntu. I didn't find any compatible drivers and now trying to print via RS-232 interface in this device.
When I installed driver for printer via serial port in Windows - all is working. 
But when I trying to print some examples on PPLA, PPLB, PPLZ languages - nothing. Ready light is blinking - data is receiving, but nothing happens. When I power off than power my printer - it writes in console "R" symbol - as I understand, I made correct com port speed (9600 8n1 XON/XOFF).
And such command, as "T" does nothing :(

Communication log: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17149297/argox.PNG

Can anyone help to solve this problem - I need to print stickers in Ubuntu Linux - using drivers or write commands directly is not matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer yourself - "STX" is 0h02 char code - that's my mistake.

Any more I can print directly into raw printer in Ubuntu:
*lp -d Argox -o raw test.ppla*